# Ubuntu /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l

Tags: linux, ubuntu

```
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lX11
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXext
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXxf86dga
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lXxf86vm
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
cons: *** [release-x86-Linux-2.1/full/unix/wolfsp.x86] Error 1
cons: errors constructing release-x86-Linux-2.1/full/unix/wolfsp.x86
```

Can't fix this error when compiling RTCW. I installed the mentioned libraries but it still doesn't work

Answer (score 1):

This is a problem of argument order: Options must not follow an object file. If they do, they are interpreted as object file names, and consequently not found.